# fgets unpredicted behavior after reading '\n'

Tags: c, sockets, newline, system-calls, fgets

Trying to code echo server\client in C, based on sockets.
I can't understand how fgets() works for sure.

> If a newline is read, it is stored into the buffer. A terminating null
>   byte ('\0') is stored after the last character in the buffer.

```
 while (fgets(sendline, MAXLINE, stdin) != NULL) {
  sendline[strlen(sendline)-1] = '\0';
  send(sockfd, sendline, strlen(sendline), 0);}
```

But what I get on server:

```
String received from and resent to the client:1234567890

String received from and resent to the client:abc
567890
```

as you can see, '\n' char added to second line, and tries to override first, with new line. But on client, I see that buffer have no '\n' while use send().

Hitting ctld+D (EOF) works as expected.

How to prevent this? And send using Enter key?

This picture expain what I mean. And there is no change after comment certain lines of code (for @PCLuddite)
[image]

Comment: Use `'\0'` instead of `'0'` — there's a lot of difference between digit 0 and a null byte.

Comment: warning: if the input exceeds MAXLINE then fgets will split the input to fit in buff, and then, the only last part that has the '\n' char at the end.

Comment: Now I think it's not about fgets(), but recv(). Because behavior stands still even after memset(&sendline, 0, strlen(sendline));

Comment: @milevyo It's noe exceed, I tried very low amount of chars, MAXLINE = 4096

Comment: because you are sending only strlen(sendline) the null char is not included. in recv of the client you have to include it your self, or send strlen(sendline)+1.

Comment: am I need null char, at least?

Comment: As part of the problem could be in the receiving code, posting that would aide in solving the issue.

Comment: @chux Yeah, I thought about this too, right at third comment in this thread. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Certainly the receiving end is not forming a string, just an array of `char` with no null character.  Send a +1 to include the null character. [@milevyo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33314299/fgets-unpredicted-behavior-after-reading-n#comment54427775_33314299)

```
while (fgets(sendline, sizeof sendline, stdin) != NULL) {
  size_t length = strlen(sendline);
  if (length > 0 && sendline[length-1] == '\n') {
     sendline[--length] = '\0';
  }
  send(sockfd, sendline, length + 1, 0);  // + 1
}
```

Comment: or use sizeof instead strlen()

Comment: @kAldown No, `sizeof` will return the size of the buffer, not the string contained in the buffer.

Answer (score 0):

There is a difference between '0' and '\0'. '0' means it takes that as a integer 0. So, you have to give '\0' or you have to give the 0 without the single quote. In char the 0(Without the single quote) is a NULL.

So, if you want remove the new line in the input, you can use the below example.

Example:-

```
char Buf[BUFSIZ];
while(fgets(Buf,BUFSIZ,stdin)!=NULL) {
   if(Buf[strlen(Buf)-1]=='\n') { //Prevent from EOF
      Buf[strlen(Buf)-1]='\0'; // Remove newline from Buf
      send(sockfd, Buf, strlen(Buf), 0);
   }
}
```

Comment: Is this a joke? What code difference between your answer and my question?

Comment: @kAldown That was not your original code. Your original code contained an error that was relevant to the problem you were experiencing.

Comment: Note: `Buf[strlen(Buf)-1]=='\n'` is undefined behavior in the rare situation when `Buf[0]== 0`.  Better to use `Buf[strcspn(Buf, "\n")] = '\0';`

Comment: @PCLuddite are you sure? This is not a solution. Or even close one to solve a problem, More over, this is exactly block of code I have in project, and it makes no sense, because I talk about hitting Enter, which lead to newline, which still be handled by replasing last char from '\n' to 0, or I'm wrong?

Comment: @kAldown I'm sure that it wasn't your original code (that's why I rolled back your edit). This may not be a complete solution (I haven't looked at your problem closely), but it's certainly not a joke.

Comment: @PCLuddite ok, as you wish, don't waste my time, and try with, and without this diff, and you'll ses that this makes <b>no</b> change in certain scenario.

Comment: @kAldown It could be handled by trading `'\n'` with a NULL character, `'\0'` not `'0'`. But again, that could only be part of the problem.

Comment: @PCLuddite how hard to talk with you, just stop telling the same. And think before.

Comment: @kAldown I'm trying to explain this to you calmly, but it seems like you're becoming very agitated. All I'm saying is that the above is contributing to your problem. It may not be the whole problem, but it's a problem. Don't bite the hand that feeds you.

Comment: @PCLuddite ok, lets talk from another angle, to what exactly problem it could lead, and why you think it's a problem?

Comment: @kAldown These comments have become off-topic to this answer. I won't be replying to anymore of them. Please read chux's answer to see if that is also relevant to your problem.

Comment: @PCLuddite it was a pleasure talking to you and hear "I won't reply anymore" right after I ask you why. Good day to you sir.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, problem was in server receive  block.
I should use memset() right after puts();
Or even don't use puts(), will read difference between different sys.calls.

in server.c:

```
while ( (n = recv(connfd, buf, MAXLINE,0)) > 0)  {
   printf("%s","String received from and resent to the client:");
   puts(buf);
   memset(&buf, 0, strlen(buf));
}
```

Or only swap sizeof and strlen() in client.c:

```
while (fgets(sendline, MAXLINE, stdin) != NULL) {
  if (sendline[(strlen(sendline)-1)] == '\n') {

      sendline[strlen(sendline)-1] = '\0';

      //send(sockfd, sendline, strlen(sendline)+1, 0);
      send(sockfd, sendline, sizeof sendline, 0);
  }
```

Now strings doesn't override themselves.

Comment: Couple problems.  #1 "I should use memset() right after puts();" is insufficient.  The null character needs to be appended at the end of `connfd` _before_ calling `puts()`.  The `memset()` is too late. Simple use `buf[n] = 0;` before `puts()`.  No need to call `memset()`.

Comment: #2 is more subtle.  Should the user send a blank line, that is 0 `char`, then this routine will not do the `puts("")` which prints a `’\n’`.  The simple solution to this and #1, is to send the `’\0’` as answered [elsewhere](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33314913/2410359).

Comment: #3 Minor: No need for `&` in `memset(&buf, 0, ...`.

Comment: memset() is not the correct solution, but workaround to solve the problem. If suggestion from @milevyo (in comments to the question) is followed, then, memset() is not required at all.

Comment: Note: `sendline[(strlen(sendline)-1)]` can be exploited by hackers. It is possible to enter from the keyboard the null character.  Entry could be `'\0'`, `'a'`, `'b'`, `'c'`, `'\n'`, then `fgets()` appends the trailing `'\0'`.  Now `strlen(sendline)` returns 0 and `sendline[(strlen(sendline)-1)]` is accessing outside the range of `sendline` leading to undefined behavior.

Comment: @chux Thanks, this project just for security homework in my college. Appreciate for sharing this knowledge :D